# How do I hide the west-Area on a borderlayout?

Tags: zk, border-layout

When I hide the borderlayout I do not want a frame displayed, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: any example to demonstrate the issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the frame/border on the parts of a `borderlayout` by setting `border="none"`.

```
<borderlayout>
  <west border="none">
  </west>
</borderlayout>
```

It's in the [ZK borderlayout example](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Layouts/Borderlayout), though not very explicit. Notice the "Here is a non-border" panel.

---

PS: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future please be more specific with your questions; you'll get much better interest and more useful responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the west-Area to '0px' how you will get it back to the original width?
west.setWidth("0px");